# Metamask not switching chain to Rinkeby testnet

Tags: web3js, metamask, ethers.js, rinkeby

I am trying to call this function which will trigger metamask to change the chain to rinkeby test net but it's not working, It is working for other chains like polygon mainnet and binance mainnet but for Rinkeby it not doing anything

```
await window.ethereum.request({
    method: 'wallet_switchEthereumChain',
    params: [{
       chainId: `0x${Number(4).toString(16)}`,
       chainName: "Rinkeby",
       nativeCurrency: {
          name: "Rinkeby Ether",
          symbol: "RIN",
          decimals: 18
       },
       rpcUrls: ["https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/"],
       blockExplorerUrls: ["https://rinkeby.etherscan.io"]
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mixed up the functions for "switching" and for "adding" a network. The function to switch network should only have to pass the chainId.

This is what my code looks like:

```
let web3 = window.ethereum;

await web3
  .request({
    method: "wallet_switchEthereumChain",
    params: [{ chainId: chainId }],
  })
  .catch(() => {});
```